# React Native NativeModules.TextViewManager is null

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to extend the built in react native TextInput component with a method to return the text selection rectangles for a given range. I followed this pattern [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1908) but I'm stuck at this step

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var TextViewManager = NativeModules.TextViewManager;
```

TextViewManager is always null. Does anyone know why or how to get access to TextViewManager so I can call the method I've added to it?

I've tried accessing other managers (eg. WebViewManager) in the same way and it's worked a treat. It just seems like TextViewManager is a special case.

Comment: I logged the NativeModules but inside that, there is no TextViewManager...

Comment: Thanks for checking @JainZz . It appears for me when I log NativeModules, thought it's always null. `TextViewManager: [Getter/Setter],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got itworking and it was because I didn't run `react-native run-ios` after changing my TextViewManager category source in Xcode. I mistakingly thought `react-native log-ios` built, installed and logged but it only logs.